# VB.NET using regex to get between single quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm downloading the source code from a webpage into a string, how would I parse this line out of it? Here's the line I'm looking for:

> $rt.set('ufAC', 'f4bc76cae020e84df25faebc140f4503fb17ba9c');

This part here changes:

> f4bc76cae020e84df25faebc140f4503fb17ba9c

But it stays at 40 characters everytime.

This is how I'm trying to do it

```
 Dim htmlPage As String
    Dim wc As New WebClient()
    htmlPage = wc.DownloadString("websitehere")
    wc.Dispose()

    Dim token As String = Regex.Match(htmlPage, "$rt.set('ufAC', '(.*)');").Groups(0).Value




    MessageBox.Show(token)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
Dim token As String = Regex.Match(htmlPage, "\$rt\.set\('ufAC', *'.{40}'\);").Groups(0).Value
```

i.e. escape all special regex meta characters like `$` `(` `.` `)` etc and use `.{40}` to match a string of 40 characters.